# How to match strings that are entirely composed of a predefined set of substrings with regex

Tags: regex

How to match strings that are entirely composed of a predefined set of substrings. For example, I want to see if a string is composed of only the following allowed substrings:

- ,
- 034
- 140
- 201

In the case when my string is as follows:

> 034,201

The string is fully composed of the 'allowed' substrings, so I want to positively match it.
However, in the following string:

> 034,055,201

There is an additional 055, which is not in my 'allowed' substrings set. So I want to not match that string.

What regex would be capable of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(034|201|140|,)+$
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/CE5IZ0/1)

Step by step:

- `^` begining of a line
- `(034|201|140|,)` captures group with alternative possible matches
- `+` captured group appears one or more times
- `$` end of a line

Comment: This is concise and would match strings like `,140` or `034,`

Comment: Yes, but there were no such limitation in @Geert van den Burg question

Comment: thanks! I was thinking in the wrong direction (with negations and stuff). It is easier then I thought. Although this also matches strings like `,140` and `034,`, that is ok for the data I am working with and as it is simple, it should also be fast.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match only your values and ensure that the line doesn't start or end with a comma. Only matches in group 0 if it is valid, the groups are non-matching.

`^(?:034|140|201)(?:,(?:034|140|201))*$`

- `^`: start
- `(?:034|140|201)`: non-matching group for your set of items (no comma)
- `(?:,(?:034|140|201))*`: non-matching group of a comma followed by non-matching group of values, 0 or more times
- `$`: end